# How can I sync worlds from my phone to console?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I have an iPhone SE running iOS 12.4 with minecraft 1.12.0 and a nintendo switch with bedrock 1.12.0. I have downloaded an addon world to my phone and I want to get it on my nintendo switch. Is there any way I can do this without a computer?

Answer (score 1):

Turn the world on pocket edition to a .mcworld file.

You can do this by zipping all content from the world file in file explorer on the iPhone, and then renaming the file from "yourWorldName.zip" to "yourWorldName.mcworld. You should be able to find the original world file under "games/mojang/minecraftworlds/yourWorldName".

This type of file can be opened by any device, so you can import it to your switch.

Comment: It says "This folder is empty"